# FileNotFoundException in JBoss AS 7

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss7.x, filenotfoundexception

I have a maven project set up in eclipse 4.2.1 (build 20121004-1855). The project has (among others) two necessary dependencies configured in the pom.xml which are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev16-1.8.0-beta</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

The first library allows me to connect with google calendar services and interact with them. The second library enables me to process JSON.

The problem is that when i try to deploy the project in JBoss AS 7, i get the following error:

```
17:31:09,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 8392ms - Started 178 of 255 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
17:43:12,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 5) JBAS014900: Content added at location /usr/local/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/content/c6/3443036ca32a120acc8adf87de993f18a60175/content
17:43:12,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "eventes.war"
17:43:14,046 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpclient-4.0.3.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,047 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpcore-4.0.1.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,048 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpclient-4.0.3.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,049 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpcore-4.0.1.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,051 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpclient-4.0.3.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,053 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpcore-4.0.1.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,054 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry commons-codec-1.6.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,057 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpclient-4.0.3.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,058 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry httpcore-4.0.1.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,059 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,060 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,061 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,061 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/content/eventes.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
17:43:14,099 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar".main: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-api-client-1.11.0-beta.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:116) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:63) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:43:14,097 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/guava-11.0.1.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/guava-11.0.1.jar".main: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/guava-11.0.1.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/guava-11.0.1.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:116) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:63) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:43:14,097 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar".main: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:116) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:63) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:43:14,097 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.external./home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar".main: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:116) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ExternalModuleSpecService.start(ExternalModuleSpecService.java:63) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:43:14,210 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 5) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "eventes.war" was rolled back with failure message JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete
17:43:14,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment eventes.war in 36ms
```

I know that the problem is in those dependencies because i have another very similar project that doesn't have those two dependencies, and it doesn't have any problems. If i put those depencies in the working project, it doens't deploy anymore, and gives the above message.

I'm starting out with JBoss AS 7 and i've search everywhere for a solution. Can someone give me a light? Does anyone know what means this line in the above error "/home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/" ?

I'm really frustrated with this one.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: insted of just giving the name of jar in your `pom.xml`, give the relative path to that jar with respect to the directory the `pom` is in.. the above error states that the jar is not found in the path `/home/codegen/dependencies/java/stable/dependencies/libs/` , which seems to be the default path its looking at.

Answer (score 0):

An issue, relating this problem, has been opened. You can see it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=642).